# saving HTML table in "file.html" to excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

There was a recent [Microsoft patch](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3098898/microsoft-windows/excel-refusing-to-open-files-blame-the-kb-3115322-3115262-security-updates.html) that broke html -> xls exports (which has since been [fixed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3115476)).

Our current export process, basically just outputs what's within a repeater as an HTML string, and saves it as ".xls".  This in turn causes a "file in different format..." warning when opening the file, and until the break patch, this was fine as you could confirm the warning, and still open the document.

There has been a patch that fixed this functionality that was introduced, but regardless I'm tasked with looking into a way to take the clients patch level out of the equation, and put it on our server's patch level.  Actually the request is to recreate all of the exports, but I'm hoping there's an easier way, as the current is very generic and handles.  Anyway...

test.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test Row 1</td>
                    <td>Test Row 2</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>0</td><td>Test 0</td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td>Test 1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>2</td><td>Test 2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>3</td><td>Test 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>4</td><td>Test 4</td></tr>
                <tr><td>5</td><td>Test 5</td></tr>
                <tr><td>6</td><td>Test 6</td></tr>
                <tr><td>7</td><td>Test 7</td></tr>
                <tr><td>8</td><td>Test 8</td></tr>
                <tr><td>9</td><td>Test 9</td></tr>
                <tr><td>10</td><td>Test 10</td></tr>
                <tr><td>11</td><td>Test 11</td></tr>
                <tr><td>12</td><td>Test 12</td></tr>
                <tr><td>13</td><td>Test 13</td></tr>
                <tr><td>14</td><td>Test 14</td></tr>
                <tr><td>15</td><td>Test 15</td></tr>
                <tr><td>16</td><td>Test 16</td></tr>
                <tr><td>17</td><td>Test 17</td></tr>
                <tr><td>18</td><td>Test 18</td></tr>
                <tr><td>19</td><td>Test 19</td></tr>
                <tr><td>20</td><td>Test 20</td></tr>
                <tr><td>21</td><td>Test 21</td></tr>
                <tr><td>22</td><td>Test 22</td></tr>
                <tr><td>23</td><td>Test 23</td></tr>
                <tr><td>24</td><td>Test 24</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which looks like this opened in excel:

[image]

I'm (attempting) to use excel interop, to open the file, and resave it as a xls/xlsx extension (hoping it will be similar to a manual "save as" from excel), at which point the warning about different document format will go away (hopefully).

I would have thought it'd be as simple as this:

```
string htmlFilePathAndName = @"C:/test.html";
string newXlsxFilePathAndName = @"C:/test.xlsx";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xls;
xls = excel.Workbooks.Open(htmlFilePathAndName);
xls.SaveAs(newXlsxFilePathAndName, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook); // exception
```

but I get an exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Microsoft Exce
>   l cannot access the file 'C://7A133BE0'. There are several possible reasons:
>
> The file name or path does not exist.
>
> The file is being used by another program.
>
> The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workb
>   ook.
>
> at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.SaveAs(Object Filename, Object Fi
>   leFormat, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object ReadOnlyRecommended,
>   Object CreateBackup, XlSaveAsAccessMode AccessMode, Object ConflictResolution, O
>   bject AddToMru, Object TextCodepage, Object TextVisualLayout, Object Local)

I'm not sure what the "7A133BE0" comes from, but I'd guess it's a temporary working file, as the value changes with each attempted run.

Is there another way to do what I'm trying to do, in a programmatic way?  I'd really like to avoid trying to recreate the website tables in a viewmodel and attempting to find a generic way to write out said viewmodel in closedxml

Comment: Write access to the root of C: is denied by default, try another location ...

Comment: @AlexK. I have updated to work in a `C:/test/` folder, but it did not correct the issue, I'm still getting that several character "7A133BE0" like exception

Comment: runs fine for me, the path slashes must be in the opposite direction though, so replace "/" for "\"

Comment: @Innat3 omfg... i'm dumb

Comment: @Kritner we all derp ever so often :D

Comment: You're generating these files using Excel Interop now? And you're on a server? That is a *bad* **terrible** idea. First your company generates HTML files masquerading as Excel files, then you use something on the server [that's not recommended for server use](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757). Instead, use a native library capable of generating actual XLSX files such as EPPlus, NPOI, or Open XML SDK.

Comment: @mason no, we aren't generating with interop, the functionality is simply writing html to a file, and naming it .xls.  The interop is used elsewhere, but (unfortunately) not my call.  (Seemingly) Lots of people are using excels interpretation of HTML in this manner, see numerous responses here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2d84793-9920-45e3-baef-5027a4ac1ae0/kb3170008-for-office-2016-breaks-functionality-ms16088 I know it's not the best way to do it for sure.

Comment: It's a terrible way. Microsoft broke that functionality for a reason, and only reversed course because there's a lot of developers out there that are following this terrible practice. There are still issues with your approach. Likely only Excel running on Windows knows what to do with an HTML file with an XLS extension. But there's also people that use Excel for iOS/Android, Spreadsheets for Mac or iOS, LibreOffice for desktop platforms. I doubt those know what to do with these files. It may not be your decision, but point out that proper practice is generating real XLSX files.

Comment: @mason I agree completely, and have already voiced concerns, which were then disregarded ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the file path
@"C:/test.html";
@"C:/test.xlsx";

should be

@"C:\test.html";
@"C:\test.xlsx";

Please rate the answere if this helps you.